# node.jsでAPIを呼び出してリザルトをreturnしたい

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, api

GASを使用して以下のAPIを作成しデプロイしました。

```
// Getメソッド用
function doGet(e) {
    var p = e.parameter;
    var translatedText = LanguageApp.translate(p.text, p.source, p.target);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(translatedText);
}
 
// Postメソッド用
function doPost(e) {
    var p = JSON.parse(e.postData.getDataAsString());
    var translatedText = LanguageApp.translate(p.text, p.source, p.target);
 
    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
    output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    output.setContent(JSON.stringify({ result: translatedText }));
 
    return output;
}
```

これをnodejsで呼び出すために次のコードを記述しました。

```
const request = require('request');
const url = デプロイしたURL;

function translate(txt, src, tget){
    request.get({
        uri: url,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        qs: {
            text: txt,
            source: src,
            target: tget
        },
        json: true
    }, function(err, req, data){
        return data;
    });
};

const result = translate('Hello, World!', 'en', 'ja');
console.log(result);
```

これを`node translate.js`と実行すると、

```
undefined
```

が返されます。
また、特にエラーは発生していませんでした。

`return data;`を`console.log(data);`に置換し最後の2行のコードを消すと`こんにちは世界！`という想定していた返り値が表示されました。

`こんにちは世界！`のように正常にreturnできるようにするコードを教えてください。

開発環境：
nodejs 18.18.0
npm 9.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `undefined` が返されます。

translate は非同期で動くので、応答が返ってくるのを待たずに `console.log(result);` が実行されるからだと思います。

なので、質問者さんが行ったように、応答が返ってくると呼ばれるコールバック function の中で処理するのが正解だと思います。

---

**【追記】**

JavaScript で今回のように API を呼び出す場合は Promise, async/await を使う fetch API を利用することが多いと思います。

フェッチ API の使用
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

具体的な使用例は以下の記事の「クライアント側 (MVC の View)」のコードを見てください。

Web API に CORS 実装 (CORE)
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2023/01/21/aspnet-core-web-api-with-cors-middle-ware.aspx

Node.js でも node-fetch をインストールすると使えるようになるそうです（未検証・未確認です）。試してみてはいかがでしょう。

Node.jsでAysnc/Awaitを使ってHTTPリクエストを行う5つの方法
https://www.twilio.com/ja/blog/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-node-js-using-async-await-jp